# ON DELETE CASCADE support?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

As the title says, I'm trying to delete an object using Entity Framework, MySQL and CodeFirst.

I have a many-to-many relations in my object, and I only remove one convention:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

in my context. But I still get this when trying to delete:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`jagtartjagtrejse`, CONSTRAINT `JagtArt_JagtRejser_Target` FOREIGN KEY (`JagtRejse_JagtRejseID`) REFERENCES `jagtrejse` (`JagtRejseID`))
```

Is on delete cascade not supported in mysql connector, or is something wrong?

Comment: These questions may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334619/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905470/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Comment: Thank you, but they do not unfortunately, as it's related to Entity Framework and CodeFirst specifically, I don't (and shouldn't) touch any SQL DDL.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532950/965013

I believe this answers your question. The link shows how to disable cascade on delete, but as you will see, turning it on is simply a matter of calling

```
modelBuilder.Entity<...>() 
        .HasRequired(...) 
        .WithMany(...) 
        .HasForeignKey(...) 
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

By forcing `cascadeDelete: true` in *EF migration file*, I get the same result.

`ON DELETE` is set to `RESTRICT`, when it should be `CASCADE`.
I have to manually change the `FK` to get it work.

Edit : Bug filed on Mysql bug tracker.