# Code first Many to Many Constraint error

Tags: entity-framework, constraints, fluent

I have the following fluent mapping:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany<Device>(user => user.Devices)
                .WithMany(sv => sv.Users)
                .Map(userDevice =>
                {
                    userDevice.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                    userDevice.MapRightKey("DeviceId");
                    userDevice.ToTable("UserDevice"));
                });
```

Inside User:

```
public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
```

Inside Device:

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Now I receive the following error:

> {"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.UserDevice_dbo.Device_DeviceId' on table 'UserDevice' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.  Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."}

I would love to set "WillCascadeOnDelete(false)" but this option is not available on "WithMany()"

I also found the following solution but I do not want to disable cascade delete completely:
[Entity Framework Many to Many Cascade Delete Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779611/entity-framework-many-to-many-cascade-delete-issue)

Comment: I think your constraint is slightly off.   Do you get the same error if you use `HasMany()` instead of `HasMany<Device>()`?

Comment: the problem is the `Map`. WillCascadeOnDelete should be ok after the WithMany. Do you really need to set the table and keys for the link table ?

Comment: @OleAlbers Could you post the code for the models? I suspect there is another conflicting relationship.